# php cookies error - http setcookie over request only

Tags: php, http, cookies

```
function setingCookie($cookieArr,$cookie, $value, $default = null,$validity = null, $httponly = true) {
   echo $_COOKIE[$cookieArr];

    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookieArr])) {
        echo"set";
    }

    else echo"not";

  if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookieArr])) {
        echo 'setting cookie ';
        setcookie(
            $cookieArr,
            $value,
          //$json_encoded,
           $validity);
    }
}


setingCookie("pmaauth","pmauser","hintu");
setingCookie("pmaauth","pmapass","mypass");
```

I want to reduce my cookie usage, so i am creating a array and adding values to it if it is already set in cookies.

Kindly help out , this produces not set not set , i want something like not set and then set .
setcookie is sent with http request, so any workaround will be appreciated .
Single request is something that is required.

Comment: What is `$cookieArr`?

Comment: i need to check if cooke array (json format) if exists then pushback in array , cookieArr is the name of the cookie set which will have value as json array